# Why is there no end user Application, yet?

Tags: machine-learning

machine learning is being hyped since the deep neural networks.

It seems to me, that you have to program in order to do machine learning.
But is the process of training data and labeling data is the same of every problem. Why isn't there an Excel like application that enables thousands of non experts to do machine learning ?

Disclaimer : I am not a data scientist .

Comment: Look at Watson analytics. Bring data and does supervised learning. Is this what you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing 2 examples:
[IBM Watson Analytics](https://www.ibm.com/marketplace/cloud/watson-analytics/us/en-us)

[Amazon ML use case](https://www.ibm.com/marketplace/cloud/watson-analytics/us/en-us)

Preparing the data for supervised learning is require skills. Not all data came labeled and in form to be used as in need to solving problems.

Also many more platforms/Api are in market now but for sure you can't solve a problem only with 1 algorithm, is needed much more ... Hope it help.